# How to filter in deep nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

Could you please assist me on working out how can I filter for a specific property within a deep nested array of objects?

I want to be able to search for entire array (including parent itself and children) where _speciality is 'can fly'.  As such, in the above, I should get 2 values back (fruit1, fruit3).

I have tried to usual JS operations like .filter, .map but unable to work out how this can be achieved.

Here is what my object looks like:

```
const foo = {
    "fruits": [
        {
              "fruit1": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "square", "size": "large"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "delhi", "location": "23 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "10kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]    
              }]
        },
        {
            "fruit2": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "round", "size": "small"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can sing"}]      
              }]        
        },
        {
            "fruit3": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "rectangle", "size": "medium"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]      
              }]        
        }        
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the many solutions you are looking for

```js
const foo = {
    "fruits": [
        {
              "fruit1": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "square", "size": "large"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "delhi", "location": "23 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "10kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]    
              }]
        },
        {
            "fruit2": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "round", "size": "small"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can sing"}]      
              }]        
        },
        {
            "fruit3": [{
              "categories": { "shape": "rectangle", "size": "medium"},
              "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
              "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]      
              }]        
        }        
    ]
};

const result = foo['fruits'].filter(f => {
  const keyName = Object.keys(f)[0];
  const _speciality = f[keyName][0]['capacity'][0]['_speciality'];
  return _speciality === 'can fly';
});

console.log(result)
```

You can easily process the `result` to get the output as required. I am leaving that exercise for you but feel free to get back.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you collab-with-tushar-raj for your time and helping me with this.  This works perfectly and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tailor your filter to your data. There is no one-size-fits-all approach to this.

Your filter is going to look something like this:

```js
const canFly = data.fruits.filter(obj =>
  obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][0].capacity[0]._speciality === 'can fly');
```

In the snippet below, I introduced some intermediary variables to explain the process in more detail.

```js
const data = {
  "fruits": [{
    "fruit1": [{
      "categories": { "shape": "square", "size": "large"},
      "factories": [{ "city": "delhi", "location": "23 new road"}],
      "capacity": [{ "weight": "10kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]    
    }]
  }, {
    "fruit2": [{
      "categories": { "shape": "round", "size": "small"},
      "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
      "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can sing"}]      
    }]        
  }, {
    "fruit3": [{
      "categories": { "shape": "rectangle", "size": "medium"},
      "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
      "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]      
    }]        
  }]
};

const canFly = data.fruits.filter(obj => {
  const
    fruitKeyArr = Object.keys(obj), // We do not know the key
    fruitKey = fruitKeyArr[0], // Let's grab the first one
    fruitArr = obj[fruitKey], // The value is an array
    fruitData = fruitArr[0], // Grab the first one; again
    fruitCapacityArr = fruitData.capacity; // Access the capacity
  return fruitCapacityArr[0]._speciality === 'can fly'; // Compare
});

const keys = canFly.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(keys)); // ["fruit1","fruit3"]
console.log(canFly);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The results should be:

```json
["fruit1", "fruit3"]
```

```json
[{
  "fruit1": [{
    "categories": { "shape": "square", "size": "large"},
    "factories": [{ "city": "delhi", "location": "23 new road"}],
    "capacity": [{ "weight": "10kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]    
  }]
}, {
  "fruit3": [{
    "categories": { "shape": "rectangle", "size": "medium"},
    "factories": [{ "city": "bombay", "location": "13 new road"}],
    "capacity": [{ "weight": "14kg", "_speciality": "can fly"}]      
  }]        
}]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Polywhirl, this is most helpful. I really appreciate you taking the time and help me on this.  Also many thanks for providing your comments as well.